# Nestjs raw mongodb query

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I was wondering if there's a way to execute queries directly bypassing mongoose schemas in nestjs framework?

In my module, I am importing MongooseModule for schema

```js
@Module({
  imports: [ MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Some', schema: SomeSchema }])
  ...
})
```

Then in my controllers and services I can execute queries agains that schema:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Some') private readonly someModel: Model<Some>
  ) {
    this.userModel.findOne({ something: "some value" }).exec()
  }
}
```

If I wanted to execute more complex queries directly, how would I do that what kind of module dependencies I would need to setup?

```js
// I would like to be be able to do something like this:
this.db.some.find({})
```

Comment: is `db.some.find({})` exactly the same as `SomeModel.find({})`?

Comment: Yea, but the thing is that I want to do something like this: this.db[collectionName].find({}) where collectionName would be dynamic value

Comment: I guess what you can do is a mixin